# Wordpress Drag and Drop Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

How can we create a drag and drop widget in word press? I need to create a widget and also I need to drag it on my existing sidebar.Please anybody can give me a spark to go forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a base widget class with core functionality and you can extend the class with your own custom class and methods. Check out the following links for some good details and how to's.

- [WordPress Widget API Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)
- [Creating Custom WordPress
  Widgets](http://prothemedesign.com/how-to/creating-custom-wordpress-widgets/)
- [How to Make Your Own
  WordPress Widget](http://xavisys.com/wordpress-widget/)