# How to make drag and drop widget and put position into database

Tags: wordpress, drag-and-drop, widget

How can i make for example Worpdpress Widget.
I want a area dragged and dropped and hold its position into the database.
Does somebody has tips/ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044338/wordpress-drag-and-drop-widgets) previously posted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new plugin and open init.php file.

add following code(this is an example code for a widget)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Example: My User Widget
Description: This plugin provides a simple widget that shows the name of
the logged in user
*/
class My_User_Widget extends WP_Widget {
function My_User_Widget() {
parent::WP_Widget(false,’My User Widget’);
}
function widget($args) {
$user=wp_get_current_user();
if(!isset($user->user_nicename)) {
$message=’Welcome Guest’;
}
else {
$message=”You are logged in as {$user->user_nicename}”;
}
extract($args);
echo $before_widget;
echo “<p>$message</p>”;
echo $after_widget;
}
}
function register_my_user_widget() {
register_widget(‘My_User_Widget’);
}
add_action(‘widgets_init’,’register_my_user_widget’);
```

widgets_init hook will call register_my_user_widget method.  Then My_User_Widget Class  will be called. once you activated the widget you can see it in widgets window and drag and drop it where you want.